# Transfer data from iPhone with no password to Apple ID

Tags: iphone, itunes

My Apple ID got hacked a few months ago and it's still on the iPhone 5 and I can't access the password as it as hacked!

How can I transfer just the music from iPhone 5 to iPhone 7?

Comment: What do you mean by hacked? Can you still use your phone? Did you try to regain access to your account through iforgot.apple.com?

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't totally clear, so I'm making some assumptions (such as your Apple ID email is still the same and that you're talking about music you've purchased with that Apple ID).

As a starting point, visit [iForgot](https://iforgot.apple.com) to reset a forgotten password, unlock your account, or recover an Apple ID.

Once you've done that, you can sign in with your new password etc on your iPhone 7 and download any purchases you've made previously. Also, assuming you have a Mac/PC you can also sign in again on iTunes and use iTunes then to sync music etc across.

If I've misunderstood your issue, please clarify your question and let me know.

Comment: Indeed, the question lacks some of the CClarity it needs

Answer (score -1):

A tool called [iMazing](https://imazing.com) worked for me, when I needed messages from an old backup

Comment: How does this solve the problem the OP has?

Comment: @patrix well if he's really the owner, he probably has a backup somewhere…

Comment: Some more detailed instructions about how to use the tool or what it does might be helpful here.